# HTTP GET request desterilize with wrapper class 'non static method' error

Tags: apex, json

Hi all i'm trying to retrive data from a source which gives me a json with all of a certain property listing details such as bedrooms bathrooms etc...

so I'm trying to parse the data using a wrapper class to then display in a visualforce page...

here is my controller:

```java
public class DomainAPI {
    public List<DomainWrapperClass> ListingWrapperList{get;set;}
    
    public List<DomainWrapperClass> getperformcallout(){
        ListingWrapperList = new List<DomainWrapperClass>();
    
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        Http http = new Http();
        req.setEndpoint('callout:Domain/v1/listings/2017755932');
        req.setMethod('GET');

        res = http.send(req);
    
        if(res.getstatusCode() == 200 && res.getbody() != null){
            ListingWrapperList = (List<DomainWrapperClass>)json.deserialize(
                res.getbody(),
                List<DomainWrapperClass>.class);
        }
    
        return ListingWrapperList;
    }
```

Here is my Wrapper Class from Json to Apex using the response body.

```java
public class DomainWrapperClass {
    public class PriceDetails {
        public Integer priceFrom;
        public Integer priceTo;
        public String gstOption;
        public String priceUnit;
        public Boolean canDisplayPrice;
        public String displayPrice;
    }

    public String dateUpdated;
    public GeoLocation geoLocation;
    public String objective;
    public String status;
    public String saleMode;
    public String channel;
    public Integer id;
    public AddressParts addressParts;
    public AdvertiserIdentifiers advertiserIdentifiers;
    public ApmIdentifiers apmIdentifiers;
    public Integer bathrooms;
    public Integer bedrooms;
    public String buildingArea;
    public Integer buildingAreaSqm;
    public Integer carspaces;
    public String dateCreated;
    public String dateMinorUpdated;
    public String dateListed;
    public String description;
    public String headline;
    public Boolean isNewDevelopment;
    public PriceDetails priceDetails;
    public List<String> propertyTypes;
    public ProviderDetails providerDetails;
    public SaleDetails saleDetails;
    public Boolean isWithdrawn;
    public String seoUrl;
    public Boolean homepassEnabled;

    public class ApmIdentifiers {
        public Integer addressId;
        public Integer streetId;
        public Integer suburbId;
        public Integer cadastreId;
        public Integer postcodeId;
        public Integer stateId;
        public String state;
        public Integer propertyTypeId;
        public Integer propertyTypeCategoryId;
        public String streetNumber;
    }

    public class AuctionSchedule {
        public String locationDescription;
        public String openingDateTime;
    }

    public class TenantDetails {
    }

    public class AdvertiserIdentifiers {
        public String advertiserType;
        public Integer advertiserId;
        public List<Integer> contactIds;
        public List<String> agentIds;
    }

    public class ProviderDetails {
        public String providerSystem;
        public String providerAdID;
    }

    public class GeoLocation {
        public Double latitude;
        public Double longitude;
    }

    public class AuctionDetails {
        public AuctionSchedule auctionSchedule;
    }

    public class SaleDetails {
        public String saleMethod;
        public AuctionDetails auctionDetails;
        public TenantDetails tenantDetails;
    }

    public class AddressParts {
        public String streetNumber;
        public String postcode;
        public String street;
        public String suburb;
        public String stateAbbreviation;
        public String displayType;
        public String displayAddress;
    }
}
```

Now when I try and run it I'm getting

> Non static method cannot be referenced from a static context: `List<DomainWrapperClass> DomainAPI.getperformcallout()`

any pointers on this would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever is calling `getPerformCallout` is marked as static. You need to make `getPerformCallout` static as well.

Answer (score 0):

The code calling this method needs to construct an instance of the Domain API class:

```
new DomainAPI().getperformcallout();
```

Comment: Brilliant Thank you its sending now... I am getting a ' Malformed JSON: Expected '[' at the beginning of List/Set' but i guess thats something to do with the wrapper?

Comment: @MikeCuming It sounds like you have an object, not a list. Can you share some JSON?

Comment: {
    "dateUpdated": "2022-04-29T08:10:33.783Z",
    "geoLocation": {
        "latitude": -36.7822038,
        "longitude": 144.243423
    },
    "objective": "sale",
    "status": "new",
    "saleMode": "buy",
    "channel": "residential",
    "id": 2017755924,
    "addressParts": {
        "streetNumber": "55",
        "postcode": "3550",
        "street": "Nankoor street",
        "suburb": "Bendigo",
        "stateAbbreviation": "vic",
        "displayType": "fullAddress",
        "displayAddress": "55 Nankoor street, Bendigo VIC 3550"
    },

Comment: @MikeCuming Yeah, that's apparently an object. Try changing your code to not use a List.

Comment: Hey man really appreciate the help